# Extract JS Values from Remote HTML in PHP | Scraping

Tags: php, javascript, web-scraping

I am making a dashboard for myself where I want to see the number of times an item has been downloaded from a particular site that displays this information on its site. It displays the information in graph form by using Google API, so the values are inside a `<script>` tag.

It looks like this

```
<html>
    <body>
<!--   ...somehtml    -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Uses');
    data.addRows([['9 May', 1],['22 May', 14],['23 May', 27],['24 May', 23],['25 May', 5],['26 May', 10],['27 May', 20],['28 May', 14],['29 May', 9],['30 May', 8],['31 May', 3],['1 Jun', 2],['2 Jun', 4],['4 Jun', 4],['5 Jun', 2],['6 Jun', 4],['7 Jun', 6],['8 Jun', 7],['9 Jun', 9],['10 Jun', 14],['11 Jun', 6],['12 Jun', 8],['13 Jun', 14],['14 Jun', 13],['15 Jun', 13],['16 Jun', 19],['17 Jun', 4],['18 Jun', 4],['19 Jun', 3],['20 Jun', 1],['22 Jun', 3],['23 Jun', 10],['24 Jun', 3],['25 Jun', 8],['26 Jun', 5],['27 Jun', 10],['28 Jun', 45],['29 Jun', 23]]);        
    var options = {
              width: 277, height: 136,
              title: 'Usage Statistics This Month',
              titlePosition: 'none',
              legend: {position:'none'},
              chartArea: {left:0, top:24, width:277, height: 110},
              hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'}, vAxis: {textPosition: 'in'}
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
...somehtml    
    </body>
</html>
```

The data I want is the one after "data.addRows". I am new to scraping so I couldn't find a way to do this. I wonder if I can get the values stored in an array of this format:

**Example :**

For -> ['9 May', 1]

I need it to be in the array with **'23 Jun' as the key** and **10 as value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://x.com/scriptname.html');
preg_match_all('/\[\'(.*?)\',(.*?)]/i', $file,$result);

for ($i = 0; $i <count($result[0]); $i++) {
        echo $result[1][$i];
        echo ':';
        echo $result[2][$i];
        echo '<br/>';
}
```

With this regex you're extracting the numbers and dates.

However if you want the array you've requested:

```
$datearray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <count($result[0]); $i++) {
        $datearray[$result[2][$i]] = $result[1][$i];
}

print_r($datearray);
```

Comment: I got an error on running this script `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in \location\to\file\index.php on line 3`

Comment: Sorry buddy, updated the code. Works now; was a bit too quick with my answer :-) here you go!

Comment: You could use the same Regex principle to first filterou: data.addRows(); part. And then release the solution on the regex on that line.